# How can I reproduce the original color scheme in a raster-plot?

Tags: r, gis

I am trying to plot [this raster file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1791181/ASTGTM2_N22E086_dem_shade_color.tif) in R using this code:

```
df = raster("/path.file.tif")
plot(df, interpolate=T)
```

The plot should look like this:
[image]

But why is the output is looking like below:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `plotRGB` and `brick`, by default raster only reads one band from a multi-band data set.  With `raster()` you are probably only getting the first band, which usually would be "Red", and probably  an unsigned integer (values between 0-255). The `plot(df)` is then giving you the default `terrain.color` palette stretched over these values.

This is tested with your file:

```
require(raster)

df = brick("C:/temp/ASTGTM2_N22E086_dem_shade_color.tif")
plotRGB(df, interpolate = TRUE)
```

This is a smaller example, reproducible from `?plotRGB`:

```
require(raster)
b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
plotRGB(b, interpolate = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi mdsumner... plotRGB() just produced a better image, but in grayscale. The original geotiff file is downloadable from the link in my post, by the way. It's a bit large, though.

Comment: Looks fine to me, did you actually use brick (or just raster())? Also, next time do at least zip up the TIFF, it's not compressed internally.

Comment: Actually that would not come out grey, so I don't know.

Comment: Ahh... Perfect. I actually did brick(raster()). Now it works great. Many thanks.